# partial implementation of abstract method of an abstract class

Tags: java, oop, interface, abstract

I have a class that is abstract called **MyAbstractClass**.

I have 5 different classes that extend it: classes **A,B,..E**

I need to add a method **foo()** in class **MyAbstractClass** but only **A,B and C**
should implement it whereas **D** and **E** will never need to execute it. (program flow will not reach there)

What would be a good practice in Java to achieve this behavior?

Should I use an interface?

Should I add another layer of inheritance two differentiate between them and add foo only in the middle layer?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see three basic approaches here:

**The child class does nothing if the method is called**

In this case, you could log the call or a warning that it was called, and just do nothing else.

**The child class should never perform the method**

In this case, you could throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

**D and E are fundamentally different than [A, B, and C]**

If the three implementing classes are similar in a way that differs from D and E, consider making a parent class of the three that is itself a child of your superclass. This may not make sense if all five classes represent similar concepts, however.

**Make an interface for A, B, and C**

As suggested by yuz and Eiko, you can make an interface for this particular method which only A, B, and C implement. If you're handling superclass reference types, you can then check if `obj instanceof MyInterface` to determine if the method should be run.

If you're using Java 8+ and there is no functional difference between A, B, and C's method in question, you can define a `default` method in the interface which all of the implementing classes can use.

Comment: Ins't there a similar solution using an interface that only A,B and C are implementing (for example "Interface Fooable") regardless to the abstract class?

Comment: I'd add the option of switching to interfaces, maybe with default implementations (if Java 8 or newer, and it's "stateless enough").

Answer (score 1):

I see two approaches:

- make default implementation of `foo` in the parent class that does nothing (an empty method) not making it abstract. In this case you override the method in descendant classes as needed.
- create interface that contains `foo` and implement that in `A`, `B` and `C`. In this case you will want to check if an object is implementing the interface having a reference to the object in `MyAbstractClass` variable, before you can actually invoke `foo`.